# String operation using regex java

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm

I have to normalize a String using java regex in following format .

> digit followed by/preceded by alphabets should be separated by space

for example

```
ABC3.5DV => ABC 3.5 DV
```

> DOT.followed by/preceded by alphabets should be separated by a space.

for example

```
Dr.Batras => Dr . Batras
```

following attempted code which is consdering `.` as alphabet.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] a = smsText.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
  if (i < a.length - 1 && i + 1 < a.length - 1)
  {

    if ((Character.isDigit(a[i]) && !Character.isDigit(a[i + 1])) || (!Character.isDigit(a[i]) && Character.isDigit(a[i + 1])))
    {
      sb.append(a[i]);
      sb.append(" ");

    } else
    {
      sb.append(a[i]);
    }

  } else
  {
    sb.append(a[i]);
  }

}
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look arounds are the best approach:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=[A-Z])(?=[.0-9])|(?<=[.0-9])(?=[A-Z])", " ");
```

The regex matches the position *between* a letter and dot-or-digit, or visa versa, and "replaces" it (ie inserts) a space.

The `(?i)` means "case insensitive", so it will work with lowercase letters too.

Comment: Try it out: online at http://fiddle.re/wej8q

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer:

```
private static String format(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9][.0-9])|(?<=[.0-9])(?=[A-Z])", " ");
}
```